# Rubymine Tests With Spring Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I'm trying to make this work by following http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/spring.html

When hitting 'run' on a test several times , no luck - I get 10 seconds of loading the environment everytime I run a test(I can see spring as an option in 'use preload servers' together with zeus , however despite choosing spring it is not working).
I'm on a mac with Rubymine 6.3 and the 'spring' gem is installed in the bundle , any advice?

Comment: ActiveSupport::TestCase